# Toggle script automatically rolled up

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I have a code

```js
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
      $('#toggle1').click(function() {
        $('.toggle1').slideToggle('slow');
                    return false;
      });
      $('#toggle2').click(function() {
        $('.toggle2').slideToggle('slow');
                    return false;
      });
</script>
```

```html
<a href="#" id="toggle1">header1</a>
<div class="toggle1" style="display:none">content1</div>
<a href="#" id="toggle2">header2</a>
<div class="toggle2" style="display:none">content2</div>
```

What should I modify to get a result when you click on the first title the second automatically rolled up and conversely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for this.

Example:

```
 $('#toggle > a').click(function () {
     var divs = $(this).siblings('div'),
         div = $(this).nextAll('div:first');
     divs.not(div).hide('500');
     div.toggle('500');
 });
```

[Demo - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLd0gung/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
      $('#toggle1').click(function() {
        $('.toggle1').slideToggle('slow');
                    return false;
      });
      $('#toggle2').click(function() {
        $('.toggle2').slideToggle('slow');
                    return false;
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="toggle1">header1</a>
<div class="toggle1" style="display:none">content1</div>
<a href="#" id="toggle2">header2</a>
<div class="toggle2" style="display:none">content2</div>
```

Check the above code this is working.

**Where you are doing wrong:**

1. You can not included any jQuery library.
2. You have added `<script>` in the JS console which should not be there.
3. You have forgot to close the `jQuery(function($) {` function with `});` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $togglers = $('.toggler');
      $togglers.click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        $togglers.next().slideUp(800);
        $(this).next().slideDown(800);
      });
});
</script>
```

```css
a + div {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="toggler">header1</a>
<div>content1</div>
<a href="#" class="toggler">header2</a>
<div>content2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle" id="toggle1">header1</a>
<div class="toggle1 toggleElem">content1</div>
<a href="#" class="toggle" id="toggle2">header2</a>
<div class="toggle2 toggleElem" style="display:none">content2</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.toggle').click(function () {
  var currnt = $(this).next(".toggleElem").slideToggle("slow");
  $(".toggleElem").not(currnt).slideUp("slow");
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/Lj62macr/**